# What happens when a question sounds on topic but answering would go off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

[This](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/91/can-i-use-several-gpus-for-a-grid-multi-screen-image) is a question about using several GPUs. As such it sounds on topic. However, a comment shows that the parallel use of GPUs is not the main problem:

> A good answer is predicated on knowing how the displays will be connected to the available GPUs (getting 9+ display outputs on a single computer isn't trivial) and the software responsible for your render. Of course it's possible to combine the processing power of multiple GPUs to solve your problem, but the devil is in the details of how the outputs are connected and how many computers are involved. –  rys

So a useful answer would address ways of getting around the restrictions on number of monitors, which seems far off topic as the only hardware questions which are on topic are GPU questions, not motherboard or cabling questions.

Should questions which would lead to off topic answers be closed as off topic or should answers explain why the question cannot be answered with computer graphics knowledge?

I'm interested in the general case in addition to this specific question.